# JQuery element unaffected by click after removeClass/addClass

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

Not sure how to explain this, but here's the JS fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/1kLsoj6h/

If you click on anything, then back to "Dashboard", it's unaffected. I'm not sure why that's happening. Here's the code:

```
$('#Dashboard').addClass('tabs_active').removeClass('tabs');

$('.tabs').click(function(){
    $('.tabs_active').addClass('tabs').removeClass('tabs_active');
    $(this).addClass('tabs_active').removeClass('tabs');
});
```

Here's the HTML for Dashboard

```
<div id="Dashboard" class="tabs ">
    <i class="fa fa-tachometer fw"></i>
    <span id="dash/dash.php" class="remove">Dashboard</span>
</div>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: just need to ensure your click selector in this case .tabs is not removed by rest of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the order of your statements. When you remove the tabs-class before adding the click-event, the #Dashboard will not be affected as it does not have the tabs-class.

```
$('.tabs').click(function(){
    $('.tabs_active').addClass('tabs').removeClass('tabs_active');
    $(this).addClass('tabs_active').removeClass('tabs');
});

$('#Dashboard').addClass('tabs_active').removeClass('tabs');
```

or just perform the click-event to select it if you prefer this (instead of the last line):

```
$('#Dashboard').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Oop, this was the solution I was looking for. The other one allows me to hover over the Dashboard button and performs the animation even when it's active. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 $('#Dashboard').addClass('tabs_active').removeClass('tabs');
```

to this

```
  $('#Dashboard').addClass('tabs_active');
```

If you remove `tabs` class from `#Dashboard`, the `$('.tabs').click(function(){` event will not be applied to it, and it will not work.

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/1kLsoj6h/2/

Comment: this works only if there is no reason to remove the class `tabs` - in this case you could ommit this also in the click-event. Otherwise see my answer.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.. I should've thought of that.